# Django - validating input without form class

Tags: django, django-forms

So basically i am trying to validate data from request.POST and then use it.

I know how to do this if i would have used a form class but i have an issue with that since the form class needs to be populated with a key from an iteration in the template.

Also i can't seem to find a way to make a class instance in the view and then populate it with the request.POST info.

So basically what i am looking for is a way to either make a formclass that i can assign the value of a field too during a for x in model: loop in template or a way to make a similar class form instance in the view then populate it with request.POST so i can validate the info.

The goal is to validate the information but i have to be able to to assign values to the form in template during a iteration.

Anyone knows how to go about this problem?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far..

Comment: Well thats the thing, i've done all i can think of and probably tried 8 different ways. Would be way to much to post it all here.

Comment: Could you be more specific of your problem, probably with an example?? From what I see, `ModelForm` can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**In Client Side:**

- Use form.serialize() to pack all the form key, value into a single object(use formData to serialize multipart data).
- Send form data using AJAX.

**In server side:**

- Parse the data received (text in request.POST and files in request.FILES).
- Validate values and save to the model.